# Is it possible to implement search on a git based CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm using a git-based CMS (Netlify CMS) and need to implement the content's search functionality. Is it possible in git-based CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Found I could use the [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-by-language) already built search functionality